# In python, can't delete the period '.'

Tags: python

Trying to figure out how to delete the period from my output. The correct answer to the assignment is: WA. EA. AI. AR. VI
My output is: WA. EA. AI. AR. VI.

I've tried using rstrip to remove the . from the output but that does not work.

Appreciate some insight to this rookie python programmer.

```
stopwords = ['to', 'a', 'for', 'by', 'an', 'am', 'the', 
'so', 'it', 'and', 'The']
sent = "The water earth and air are vital"
s_sent=sent.split()
acro = ''
for word in s_sent:
    if word not in stopwords:
       acro=acro + str.upper(word[:2])+". "            
       acro=acro.rstrip('.')
print(acro)
```

Comment: `.rstrip('.')` won't work as the last character is already `' '`. Also that's inside the loop, so you're trying to remove a character you just explicitly added. Maybe just `acro[:-2]` outside the loop?

Answer (score 4):

You `join` to save yourself from troubles of handling the left over spaces and 
 `'.'`

```
stopwords = ['to', 'a', 'for', 'by', 'an', 'am', 'the', 
'so', 'it', 'and', 'The']
sent = "The water earth and air are vital"
s_sent=sent.split()
acro = []
for word in s_sent:
    if word not in stopwords:
       acro.append( str.upper(word[:2]))
print('. '.join(acro))
```

**Output**

```
WA. EA. AI. AR. VI
```

Another simple way is to introduce a flag to check the first value and then smartly append `'. '` at the end of last value. In this way you will not have extra trailing characters

```
smart_flag = True
acro = ''
for word in s_sent:
    if word not in stopwords:
        if smart_flag:
            acro=acro+str.upper(word[:2])
            smart_flag=False
        else:
            acro=acro +". " + str.upper(word[:2])           

print(acro)
```

Just for completeness `acro.rstrip(' .'))` will strip any characters you pass in.By that I mean it will remove `'. '` as well as `' .'`

Comment: `word[:2].upper()` :)

Comment: `''.join(map(str.upper, text[:2]))` :)

Comment: Thanks for everyone's comments.  I'm taking a MOOC in python and enjoy learning how to program.  The challenge is learning which type of problem  lends itself to one type of solution vice another.  In my example, it seems as if using join after appending to a list is better suited than concatenating strings, which is what I was doing.  I definitely need more experience in the finer details such as mutating lists and formatting.  Thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your last character in `acro` is a space character. You have to either `rstrip(". ")` or `rstrip(" .")`.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be shortened to this:

```
stopwords = ['to', 'a', 'for', 'by', 'an', 'am', 'the', 'so', 'it', 'and', 'The']
sent = "The water earth and air are vital"

acro = '. '.join(word[:2].upper() for word in sent.split() if word not in stopwords)
print(acro)
```

Output:

```
WA. EA. AI. AR. VI
```

**Update:**

But, as @mad_ points out, `join` in this case would like to create a single string, first of exactly the right length, then with the right contents. But to know the right length it would like to find the lengths of all the components it is going to join, so having a list as its parameter would mean it has a size, whereas my original answer with a generator does not have a size until it has been exhausted.

So, better is:

```
acro = '. '.join([word[:2].upper() for word in sent.split() if word not in stopwords])
```

Comment: List comprehension will be faster in these cases while using `join`

Comment: @quamrana your suggestions worked  well.  can you explain in your line "why" it does not add a period at the end? I'm assuming because there are not any spaces after the I? It's a bit fuzzy to me.  thanks in advance

Comment: @mad_ can offer an explanation at the 100 level why your code does not put a period at the end?  thanks

Comment: The join function does this for you.